# Real Analysis: Prove that the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function
$$f(x) = \frac1{1+x^2}$$
is uniformly continuous on the interval $[0, \infty)$.

One part of my proof is 
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+y^2}\right| &= \left|\frac{y^2-x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right| \\
& = \frac{|y-x||y+x|}{|1+x^2||1+y^2|}\end{align*}$$

My question is how to make that to equal to $\epsilon$?

Comment: I just revised the question

Comment: Whoa, that was a mess. Please use MathJax for future questions. You can view the edit to see how this particular equation was typeset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need of the hypothesis $x,y\in[0,\infty)$, they can be arbitrary real numbers.

Notice that
$$
\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\le1
$$
so you can work with
$$
\frac{|x-y|\,|x+y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\le
|x-y|\left(\frac{|x|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}+\frac{|y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right)
$$

---

On the other hand you have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$
and so
$$
|f'(x)|=2\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\le 2
$$
so the function has bounded derivative, which implies it's Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: $< |x-y|\left( \frac{1}{1+y^2} + \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)< \epsilon, \space \therefore |x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{\left( \frac{1}{1+y^2} + \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)}?$ Is this correct? Or am I totally off?

Comment: @Zhoe We have proved that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le 2|x-y|$; so if we set $\delta=\varepsilon/2$, we have that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I understand that...So, $\left( \frac{|x|}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2)} + \frac{|y|}{1+x^2)(1+y^2)} \right) < 2?$

Comment: @egreg: you notice that $$ \frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\le1 $$. it is because we need to make $$
\frac{|x-y|\,|x+y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\le
|x-y|\left(\frac{|x|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}+\frac{|y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right)
$$ < |x-y|2?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Yes, that's the idea, which is confirmed by the derivative.

Comment: @egreg: we take a step further to say $$
\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}<1
$$ right?